# Which is a better way to force GC on ThreadLocal instance?

Tags: java

Which is a better way to force GC on ThreadLocal instance?

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer: you can't force the GC in java. Some may posts tricks but all in all you simply can't.

Well, in fact you can. With exit!

Comment: Actually you can force gc() [check my answer on this thread] using weak references and without having to exit ;)

Answer (score 3):

The simple and ugly answer:

```
System.gc();
```

This does not guarantee garbage collection of a specific object, but it will tell the VM to make an effort to perform general garbage collection.

Specifically, for a ThreadLocal variable, the contained instance of the variable will not be GC'd until the thread dies or the ThreadLocal instance is no longer accessible.  So, you will need to kill the associated thread, or you will need to discard your references to the ThreadLocal variable in order for the `System.gc()` to have any effect.

However, the very fact that you are calling this points to a larger problem in your code.  If you want to get rid of an object, simply having no references to it should be sufficient.  The VM will come along some time later and clean up your mess.

To repeat:  There is no reason that clean code should be explicitly calling GC.

Comment: Not true. ThreadLocal is implemented as a weak hash map.  The garbage collector can't reclaim memory unless you explicitly force it to do so.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no special "forced" garbage collection contract with a WeakHashMap (or with any object, for that matter).  Typically, the garbage collector will reclaim space in a weak hash map whenever the key is no longer in "regular use".

Comment: Just like any other WeakHashMap key, when a Thread is weakly referenceable, the entry is removed. Threads are "root" objects that are considered strongly referenceable while they are alive. I can (and do) stop your attempts at System.gc calls by setting system properties. Don't rely on System.gc.

Comment: erickson: That wouldn't be a performant way to implement ThreadLocal. In fact usually there is some kind of weak hash map in the thread mapping ThreadLocals to values. This can easily leak memory (use google). Who knows what the original poster meant.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin: This leak can be avoided in 1.5+ by using ThreadLocal.remove(key).  This will make the ThreadLocal available for GC (barring any other references).

Answer (score 2):

You can't force GC and in many cases when you run in a container even calling System.gc() won't help since the JVM usually set with -XX:+DisableExplicitGC. The JVM will ignore your explicit calls.

Answer (score 1):

The [jlibs library has a good utility class for garbage collection](http://code.google.com/p/jlibs/wiki/GarbageCollection). You can force garbage collection using a nifty little trick with [WeakReference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) objects.

[RuntimeUtil.gc()](http://jlibs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/core/src/main/java/jlibs/core/lang/RuntimeUtil.java) from the jlibs:

```
   /**
    * This method guarantees that garbage collection is
    * done unlike <code>{@link System#gc()}</code>
    */
   public static void gc() {
     Object obj = new Object();
     WeakReference ref = new WeakReference<Object>(obj);
     obj = null;
     while(ref.get() != null) {
       System.gc();
     }
   }
```

Comment: That guarantees not to return until the object is gc'd, but it doesn't actually do anything to force it to happen..

Comment: If you don't return until the object is gc-ed, it means you've forced the gc to run :)

Comment: .. or it never returns at all and keeps spinning.

Comment: @pjc50 calling the System.gc() is a hint to the jvm runtime to run the garbage collector. Surely if you call it often enough the gc will be run at some point in time? Either way it achieves the purpose of the user in that the remaining piece of code following the gc() method call is only executed after the runtime has performed garbage collection.

Comment: May depend of course on JVM implementation which may skip garbage collection if there are still free resources thus keeping `WeakReference`. However code works for Sun JDK 1.6 so-so reliably because I still have cases when memory increase is negative within a block-under-test with this GC procedure called before and after. I think that GC can do some extra cleanups (or it goes deeper) when memory is about to end and this GC logic is triggering inside, which gives unreliable results in general.

Answer (score 1):

A `ThreadLocal<Object>` is just a key. The actual values are stored in each`Thread`’s threadLocals weak hash map, which maps **weak** `ThreadLocal` to **strong** `Object`.

Assume that nobody else holds a reference to the `Object` in a `ThreadLocal`. Then there are two ways for the value of a ThreadLocal value to be garbage collected. First, there’s the easy way:

1. The thread finishes (internally setting its threadLocals map to `null`).
2. The garbage collector runs, deleting the `Thread`’s `ThreadLocalMap` and all unreachable `Object`s within it.

But if the thread is still running, then this sequence must happen before your `Object` can be garbage collected:

1. You lose all references to the `ThreadLocal`.
2. The garbage collector deletes the `ThreadLocal`.
3. You `set()` some number of other `ThreadLocal`s within that thread, and the `ThreadLocalMap` removes the stale entry from the map. The number needed is nondeterministic because unlike a standard `WeakHashMap`, the `ThreadLocalMap` only expunges a few stale entries at a time, and only on `set()`, not `get()`.
4. The garbage collector finally deletes the `Object`.

To mitigate the problem of slow garbage collection, you can call `ThreadLocal.remove()` from each `Thread` if that thread doesn’t need the object anymore.